# C++ Poco - How to send a notification/message to a specific thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, messaging, poco-libraries

I have this code below.

I have two different threads: `Foo` and `Bar`.
On the `main()` I want to send a message to the `Foo` thread. For this, I'm using the `NotificationQueue` from `POCO` libraries.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Poco/Notification.h"
#include "Poco/NotificationQueue.h"
#include "Poco/ThreadPool.h"
#include "Poco/Runnable.h"
#include "Poco/AutoPtr.h"

using Poco::Notification;
using Poco::NotificationQueue;
using Poco::ThreadPool;
using Poco::Runnable;
using Poco::AutoPtr;

class Message : public Notification
{
public:
    Message(std::string msg) 
        : mMsg(msg) 
    {
    }

    std::string getMsg() const
    {
        return mMsg;
    }
private:
    std::string mMsg;
};

class Foo: public Runnable
{
public:
    Foo(NotificationQueue& queue) : mQueue(queue) {}

    void run()
    {
        AutoPtr<Notification> notification(mQueue.waitDequeueNotification());
        while (notification)
        {
            Message* msg = dynamic_cast<Message*>(notification.get());

            if (msg)
            {
                std::cout << "received from Foo: " << msg->getMsg() << std::endl;
            }
            notification = mQueue.waitDequeueNotification();
        }
    }
private:
    NotificationQueue & mQueue;
};

class Bar: public Runnable
{
public:
    Bar(NotificationQueue& queue) : mQueue(queue) {}

    void run()
    {
        AutoPtr<Notification> notification(mQueue.waitDequeueNotification());
        while (notification)
        {
            Message* msg = dynamic_cast<Message*>(notification.get());

            if (msg)
            {
                std::cout << "received from Bar: " << msg->getMsg() << std::endl;
            }
            notification = mQueue.waitDequeueNotification();
        }
    }
private:
    NotificationQueue & mQueue;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    NotificationQueue queue;

    Foo foo(queue);
    Bar bar(queue);

    ThreadPool::defaultPool().start(foo);
    ThreadPool::defaultPool().start(bar);

    queue.enqueueNotification(new Message(std::string("start"))); //I want to send this message to Foo!!!

    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        Poco::Thread::sleep(100);
    }

    queue.wakeUpAll();

    ThreadPool::defaultPool().joinAll();

    return 0;
}
```

I've run my code several times, and I can see that sometimes the thread `Foo` catches the message first, but sometimes it's the `Bar` thread.

Output after running 5 times:

```
received from Foo: start
received from Foo: start
received from Bar: start
received from Bar: start
received from Foo: start
```

I know I can create a `source` and `destination` on the `message class` using like a filter. 
But this brings me two questions:

1 - If I need to create my own filtering for the messages, how can I just peek the message without removing it from the queue? For example: `Thread A` needs to send a message to `Thread B`, but the `Thread C` catches it first. So the `Thread C` needs only to peek the destination... if it isn't for them, then doesn't remove the message from the queue.

2 - Isn't there any way already on `POCO` to make this automatically? Like telling that notification is **ONLY** for that specific thread?

Comment: why don't you use different queue for different thread ?

Comment: I guess because if I have a thread that can send notifications to 100 different threads, I would have to pass all the notifications references to be able to tell to which thread I need to send. I though the best practice here would be to use one notification queue only for all threads. Am I thinking wrong? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of notification queue, you could go for Poco Events. By using two different events, EventB could be used to notify ThreadB, and EventC could be used to notify ThreadC.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).